# map timestamp to DateTime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
<% current_user.events.find(:all, conditions: ("start" > DateTime.now )).limit(5).each do |e| %>
  <%= e.start %>
<% end %>
```

I get this error msg:

```
invalid date
```

this does not work because the format is not correct.
I can use `e.start.to_date` then I can compare the e.event with TimeDate.now but I don't know how to map the value to a DateTime.

If I do it like this:

```
<% current_user.events.map! { |e| e.start.to_date }.limit(5).each do |e| %>
<%= e.start %> 
<% end %>
```

It's an array and therefore the good limit, where, select Active Record methods won't work anymore.

Basically I want to map all the start values to date then I want to compare them and show only today's events or future events but not from the past.

How would you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
current_user.events.where("start > ?", Time.now.to_date)
```